Post internal server error from moongdb atlas used project which is hosted in render
I have hosted this website in my repo in render and my repo is using mongoose atlas but before deploying these ,in local host post request was running but now their is internal server error for the post request after deploying in the render can you see the where is the error in my GitHub https://github.com/Nandeesh-nh/AirBnB.git
If you need full code please mail me I will send you full zip folder

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I work at Render.
Can you check your server logs for your app to see what error it's indicating? The client will get a 500 error, but your application should be telling you in the logs what went wrong.
From your Render dashboard, find your backend service and click on it, then go to the "Logs" entry on the left side menu, and see what's happening there.
